# Why does the output of this r1..r2 revision range include commits reachable from r2?

Tags: git, git-log

In the following graph, the last two commits are reachable from both r2 (`HEAD`) and r1 (`75ec2933~1`).

```
> git log --oneline --graph develop topic 75ec2933~1..HEAD
* 91cc860a (HEAD -> topic) 
* 1048e4d1 
* 1c28716e
| * f4a483cc (develop)
| *   b7cb53e6 
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | c7a197bd 
* | 3935a1a7 
| *   ad27a1fc 
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | 75ec2933 Merge branch 'develop' 
| * 5e55f38f 
|/
* 2effd96f          <--------------- 75ec2933~1 is r1
* ae6c987e 
* ecc2b546
```

I expected the last two commits not to be part of the output, because [the `git-log` documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-ltrevisionrangegt) says that we can use a revision range to "Show only commits in the specified revision range." Further, the revision range documentation say this [about the `r1..r2` notation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-Theememtwo-dotRangeNotation):

> ...you can ask for commits that are reachable from r2 excluding those that are reachable from r1 by ^r1 r2 and it can be written as r1..r2.

So my question is about why we can see the last two commits, which appear to be reachable from `r1`.

#### Additional Investigation

It turns out that `75ec2933~1` is not `2effd96f` but is instead `887b3cfa`. The graph above hides that, which lead to my confusion about `r2`.

```
> git log ecc2b546..3935a1a7 --oneline --graph
* 3935a1a7
*   75ec2933 Merge branch 'develop' 
|\  
| * 2effd96f 
| * ae6c987e 
* 887b3cfa 
* 62e6be09
```

Comment: You claim that `75ec2933~1` is `2effd96f` and that `2effd96f` is what `origin` resolves to, but you don't show either of these. Moreover it appears that you have `log.decorate` set (so that `f4a483cc` is labeled `develop`) but `2effd96f` is not labeled with anything, suggesting that it's *not* `origin` (which in this case is short for `origin/HEAD` which probably maps to `origin/master`, though that, too, is just a guess—you'd need to show `git branch -r` output to be sure).

Comment: @torek You're right that `75ec2933~1` is not `2effd96f`. I had mistakenly thought that `<hash>~1` refers to the commit on which `<hash>` is based.

Comment: @torek My interpretation of the term `origin` in the context of the log documentation is that `origin` refers to the left part of the `left..right` revision range.

Comment: @ElpieKay I added a quote that explains that in the revision range `r1..r2`, we should not see commits that are reachable from `r1`.

Comment: It turns out @torek gave the right hint for the answer. In the graph, `2effd96f` only appears to be `r1`, because it appears to be the parent of `75ec2933`, but it is not really the parent. That is what created the confusion.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin you are right. I gave a wrong explanation.

Comment: This is interesting, since the edit now shows `75ec2933~1..HEAD` in the input. That should exclude the (first, if there are more than one) parent of `75ec2933`. Is `75ec2933` a merge?

Comment: Yes. `75ec2933` is a merge commit @torek.

Comment: I've also added some additional investigation that might be the answer @torek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to guess a bit here (update: confirmed), but I think we have this situation:

- Commit `75ec2933` is a merge commit, i.e., has *two* parents.
- Parent #1 has some unknown hash ID (update: `887b3cfa`).
- Parent #2 is `2effd96f`.

If this is the case, the expression `75ec2933~1..HEAD` excludes parent #1, but not parent #2.  You can find out by running:

```
git rev-parse 75ec2933^@
```

(note the `@` suffix after the caret or hat `^`).  There's a fairly long explanation for the resulting `git log` output.  To demonstrate it, though, I'm going to use the Git repository for Git itself instead, since that's one I have handy.

#### Example

Here's what happens when I do that on a different merge commit in the Git repository for Git:

```
$ git rev-parse a562a11983^@
7fa92ba40abbe4236226e7d91e664bbeab8c43f2
ad6f028f067673cadadbc2219fcb0bb864300a6c
```

Here commit `a562a11983` is a merge, with parents `7fa92ba40a` and `ad6f028f06`.

If I run `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` on the Git repository for Git, allowing `git log` to start from commit `b5101f9297` (an old `master` tip—I haven't updated my Git repository for Git for weeks now), the result begins with this:

```
* b5101f9297 (HEAD -> master) Fourth batch after 2.20
*   a562a11983 Merge branch 'it/log-format-source'
|\  
| * ad6f028f06 log: add %S option (like --source) to log --format
* |   7fa92ba40a Merge branch 'js/add-e-clear-patch-before-stating'
|\ \  
| * | fa6f225e01 add --edit: truncate the patch file
* | |   371820d5f1 Merge branch 'bc/tree-walk-oid'
|\ \ \  
| * | | 974e4a85e3 cache: make oidcpy always copy GIT_MAX_RAWSZ bytes
| * | | ea82b2a085 tree-walk: store object_id in a separate member
| * | | f55ac4311a match-trees: use hashcpy to splice trees
| * | | 36775ab524 match-trees: compute buffer offset correctly when splicing
| * | | 0a3faa45b1 tree-walk: copy object ID before use
| | |/  
| |/|   
* | |   a6e3839976 Merge branch 'jt/upload-pack-deepen-relative-proto-v2'
```

Using `git log --decorate --oneline --graph a562a11983^1..HEAD` trims this to:

```
* b5101f9297 (HEAD -> master) Fourth batch after 2.20
* a562a11983 Merge branch 'it/log-format-source'
* ad6f028f06 log: add %S option (like --source) to log --format
```

Note that this graph shape looks much simpler!  I've eliminated commit `a562a11983` but not commit `ad6f028f06`, so it looks like commit `a562a11983` has one parent, `ad6f028f06`, even though it actually has two.  In effect, **`git log --graph` has lied to us.**

#### Long

It's worth noting a few more items before delving into the gritty details of `git log` itself.  First, the syntax `r1..r2`, in [gitrevisions notation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), is equivalent to `r2 ^r1`.  In fact, if we use `git rev-parse` to *expand* the syntax, that's just what we see:

```
git rev-parse a562a11983^1..HEAD
b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a
^7fa92ba40abbe4236226e7d91e664bbeab8c43f2
```

`HEAD` is the commit hash starting with `b5101`, and `a562a11983^1` (suffix `^` and number 1) is the commit starting with `7fa92b...`  Note that we've used the caret `^` as a *suffix* here, not as a *prefix;* caret as a *prefix* means *not*, i.e., exclude a revision, but caret as a suffix introduces one of the many other gitrevisions specifiers, such as `@`, `{commit}`, and of course numeric selection of a particular parent.

Another is the fact that each commit records *zero or more* parent hash IDs.  Most commits have exactly *one* parent ID.  The very first commit you ever make in a repository has no parents, for the simple reason that it *can't* have any parents: the parent ID(s) of a new commit must be existing, valid commit hash IDs.  A commit with no parents is called a *root commit*.  Some commits, typically those made by `git merge`, have two parents, and you can make multi-armed *octopus merges* that have three or more parents.  Any commit with two or more parent hash IDs is by definition a *merge commit*.

Because most commits have one parent, we typically start at the end of a chain of such commits, typically marked by a branch label such as `master`, and we can then work backwards one commit at a time:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Here the hash ID stored in the branch name `master` is represented as the uppercase letter `H`.  We say that the name `master` *points to* the commit whose hash ID is `H`.  Commit `H` itself stores the hash ID of its parent commit `G`, which stores the hash ID of commit `F`, and so on.  Hence, by starting at `H` and working backwards to `G`, then `F`, and so on, Git can show us the history—the commits—that are *reachable from* the name `master`.

The last item is that `git log` actually takes *many* starting-points (we might want to call them ending-points, but Git works backwards).  Each argument that specifies a revision—but not those that eliminate a revision due to being negated with a prefix `^`—provides such a starting point.  If you don't supply any starting points, `git log` will use `HEAD` as its starting point.

#### How `git log` walks history and then displays the graph

If we *do* have a simple linear chain like:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

then our job, if we want to emulate `git log`, is easy.  We start at commit `H` and show it.  We're now done with `H` so we walk back one step to its parent `G`.  We show `G`, then walk back to `F`.  We repeat this until we reach a root commit, which has no parent and lets us stop, or until the user quits out of `git log`.

But suppose we have a graph that has a merge commit:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M--N   <-- master (HEAD)
      \    /
       K--L
```

We'll start by showing commit `N`, then walk to `M` and show it.<sup>1</sup>  Then we'll walk to ... wait, do we walk to `J`, or `L`?

What `git log` does, in order to handle this, is keep a *priority queue* of commits it has yet to show, *while* also walking the commit graph one commit at a time.  So when you run `git log` with no additional arguments, or with `HEAD` or `master` as an argument, `git log` puts commit `N` into the queue.

When there's only one commit in the queue, the job is easy: take the one commit out of the queue, show it, and put its parent(s) into the queue if they haven't been seen before during this `git log` (which is usually the case).  When there's *more than one* commit in the queue, `git log` takes the one at the *front* of the queue, i.e., the one with the highest priority.

So, if you run `git log <start-point-1> <start-point-2> <start-point-3>`, what Git does is put *all three* starting points into the priority queue.  Since your actual command was:

```
git log --oneline --graph develop topic 75ec2933~1..HEAD
```

we had three starting points, namely `develop` (`f4a483cc`), `topic`, and `HEAD` (`75ec2933~1` is a negative reference to some hash ID).  As it turns out, `HEAD` and `topic` both name commit `91cc860a`, so the queue winds up having just the two commits in it.

The `--graph` option modifies the priority queue a bit.  The default is that the commit with the highest *date*—i.e., furthest into the future, or least in the past—goes at the front of the queue.  With `--graph` or `--topo-order`, this same rule is in place but an additional rule is added: no parent commit can be shown until all of its children that will be shown, have been shown.  In this case, that extra exception has no effect at this point as `91cc860a` and `f4a483cc` have no parent/child relationship.

So `git log` starts at whichever of those two have a later date, which is `91cc860a` aka both `HEAD` and `topic`.  Git prints this commit with a single `*` and finds its parent, `1048e4d1`, which goes into the queue.  `1048e4d1` is also newer than `f4a483cc` so Git shows it next.  It's the immediate parent of the previous commit so it's now time to show that one.  This goes on for a bit so that we see:

```
* 91cc860a (HEAD -> topic) 
* 1048e4d1 
* 1c28716e
```

`1c28716e` has parent `c7a197bd` and `c7a197bd` is an ancestor of `f4a483cc`, so it must not yet be shown, regardless of its date.  Git now begins working on showing `f4a483cc`, which is an ordinary commit:

```
| * f4a483cc (develop)
```

The parent of `f4a483cc` is `b7cb53e6` so `b7cb53e6` goes into the queue.  That commit has `c7a197bd` as an ancestor so Git shows `b7cb53e6` next:

```
| *   b7cb53e6
```

... and `b7cb53e6` is itself a merge, putting its parents `c7a197bd` and `ad27a1fc` into the queue.  But `c7a197bd` is already in the queue, so nothing happens.

Now `c7a197bd` is at the *front* of the queue, so `git log` shows it.  It's the first and only parent of `1c28716e` and the second parent of `b7cb53e6`, so `git log --graph` shows it in this slightly funky way:

```
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | c7a197bd
```

The right-extending downward leg shows this second-parent-ness.  The straight-down leg will eventually connect to the first parent of `b7cb53e6`.

This same pattern continues for a while, but then we hit the unfortunate case:

```
* | 3935a1a7 
| *   ad27a1fc 
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | 75ec2933 Merge branch 'develop' 
| * 5e55f38f 
|/
* 2effd96f          <--------------- ???
```

At this point, Git has shown commit `75ec2933` (which has two parents, `887b3cfa` which is parent #1 and `2effd96f` which is parent #2).  Git *would have* put `887b3cfa` into the queue, but we told it not to: `^75ec2933~1` means `^887b3cfa`, which means *don't show `887b3cfa`*, which keeps it out of the queue.  So having shown `75ec2933`, the queue contained commit hash IDs `5e55f38f` and `2effd96f`.  Git showed `5e55f38f`, which allowed it to move on to `2effd96f`.  When `git log --graph` showed that one, it didn't even *see* that there was a second cut-off parent, so it drew the graph incorrectly, as if that parent didn't exist.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Worth noting: when `git log` shows an ordinary commit, if `-p` is in effect, it diffs the commit vs its (single) parent so as to show the commit, which is really a snapshot, as a change.  But when it hits a merge commit, it doesn't know which parent to use for the diff, so it just doesn't bother to do a diff at all!  You can force it to show one or more diffs through additional `git log` options.

<sup>2</sup>In fairness, the in-memory representation at this point probably *doesn't* have the second parent.  The `git log` code contains some "parent rewriting" code used for history simplification, and that's probably triggered here too.

---

#### Conclusion

I usually tell people that if `git log` is showing weird results, they should add `--graph` to make it both draw the graph—well, a crude ASCII approximation anyway—and obey the graph topology when walking through commits, so that the parent/child relationships, which are often crucial, show up.  Unfortunately, when you use negation to clip away parts of the graph, this can fool the graph-drawing code into drawing lies.  Probably the graph-drawing code should be shown the true multi-parent situation, and hence be forced to draw the last part more like this:

```
|/|
* | 75ec2933 Merge branch 'develop' 
|\|
| |\
| * | 5e55f38f 
|/ /
* | 2effd96f 
* | ae6c987e 
* | ecc2b546
```

But it doesn't, so unless/until someone can add this to Git, we just have to watch out for such cases.